# Php add centered text to image

Tags: php, image

I've tried a few times but I can't seem to get 2 centered lines of text at the bottom of this image on the transparent background

Any suggestions?

```
<?php
$filePath = "adopt.png";  //full path to your png, including filename and extension

$img = @imagecreatefrompng($filePath);
$width  = imagesx($img);
$height = imagesy($img);

//create new image and fill with background color
$backgroundImg = @imagecreatetruecolor($width, $height);
imagecopy($backgroundImg, $img, 0, 0, 0, 0, 100, 130);
$color = imagecolorallocatealpha($backgroundImg, 0, 0, 0, 127); //fill transparent back

imagefill($backgroundImg, 0, 0, $color);

//save as png

header( "Content-type: image/png" );
imagepng( $backgroundImg );
imagedestroy( $backgroundImg );    
?>
```

Comment: It would be nice to see the code for your attempt.  IT would clarify what you are trying to do.

Comment: Just trying to add 2 lines of centered text at the bottom.

Comment: show us the code you have tried.

Answer (score 0):

This process works.  Without your code I can only regurgitate the example from the manual to you.  http://php.net/manual/en/function.imagestring.php.  But it works, I have used the imagestring function.  It accepts co-ordinates for the text so I can not see why it would not work for you.

```
<?php
// Create a 100*30 image
$im = imagecreate(100, 30);

// White background and blue text
$bg = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$textcolor = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 255);

// Write the string at the top left
imagestring($im, 5, 0, 0, 'Hello world!', $textcolor);

// Output the image
header('Content-type: image/png');

imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Comment: If that works for you, please tick it as the correct answer.  Thanks